# How to install ffmpeg for a django app on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, ffmpeg

I'd like to use ffmpeg to extract a frame from a video to use it as a poster. This is my first time deploying an app, let alone on heroku, so I'm not sure how to install ffmpeg on the server.

I've found [this build of ffmpeg](https://github.com/dzello/ffmpeg-heroku) with instructions to 'vendor' it into my app, and then adjust my app's configuration settings / path. What does it mean to vendor something? I have a feeling it's a rails thing, because I can't seem to find an explanation by googling.

Also, what would be the django equivalent of the instructions to run
`heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/ffmpeg/bin:<...> -a yourapp` and `heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=vendor/ffmpeg/lib:/usr/local/lib -a yourapp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to swap out the build pack for [this one](https://github.com/integricho/heroku-buildpack-python-ffmpeg):

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/integricho/heroku-buildpack-python-ffmpeg.git
```

The build pack is what takes your source code and builds what gets deployed to your Heroku dynos. This build pack explicitly includes ffmpeg with your app when it's built.

Comment: I actually saw that but was nervous to use a custom buildpack. Do you have any experience with that one? It says 'The only difference from the clean Python buildpack is that this one includes ffmpeg', which is comforting.

Comment: You can spelunk the [compile](https://github.com/integricho/heroku-buildpack-python-ffmpeg/blob/master/bin/compile) script of the relevant build pack to make sure there's no funny business going on.

Comment: Does not work for me. heroku run "ffmpeg -version" gives bash: ffmpeg: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I have searched it for 2 day, tried everything what other users said. Then i found simple way. Just go heroku app settings. Then click add buildpack. After that popups small toolbar. Add this url:

```
https://github.com/kontentcore/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg
```

press save changes. Then deploy your app again. You have done :)

[image: ffmpeg buildpack installation]