# My heroku music bot works fine if i launch it through my pc yet when i run it through heroku it doesn't work

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, bots, discord

I have ffmpeg, youtube-dl installed, i have every requirement installed, it downloads the song renames it but then nothing happens!

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            print("Removed old song file")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
        await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing")
        return

    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready now")

    voice =  get(client.voice_clients,  guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'outtmpl':"./song.mp3",
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    song_search = " ".join(url)

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([f"ytsearch1:{song_search}"])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print(f"{name} has finished playing"))
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.10

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"Currently playing: {nname}")
    print("playing\n")
```

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is, try and check your error trace on heroku.

Comment: I dont seem to get any error at all, gets to renamed file then nothing at all https://gyazo.com/b4110a13b393721c0b2a743a8fb3b4aa

Comment: Since the 'Renamed file' was logged but not the last `print(playing)` this tell me that something is going wrong in the 5 lines of code right above it. Try and add print statements between them and see exactly which one doesn't get logged. That will pinpoint the error

Comment: Ok, so i tested a bit and it seems to be this line here 
`voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print(f"{name} has finished playing"))` I am still unsure why though!

Comment: Great. See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Heroku supports ffmpeg as a buildpack to your app. Simply open you app settings at `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[app-name]/settings` and scroll down to Buildpacks, where you should add `https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git` to it.

Alternatively you can also run the CLI command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
```

#### Source:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

Comment: I have FFmpeg added as a buildpack already! Sorry  about late reply

Comment: Hmm... That's weird. Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407388/how-to-install-ffmpeg-for-a-django-app-on-heroku)?

Comment: What exactly would you like me to try?

Comment: All solutions that's there.

Comment: I am sorry in that case I am helpless. You may try hosting it on other cloud providers.